# Logarithmic function in time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

How does a program's worst case or average case dependent on log function? How does the base of log come in play?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log factor appears when you split your problem to `k` parts, of size `n/k` each and then "recurse" (or mimic recursion) on some of them.

A simple example is the following loop:

```
foo(n):
  while n > 0:
     n = n/2
     print n
```

The above will print `n, n/2, n/4, .... , 1` - and there are `O(logn)` such values.

the complexity of the above program is `O(logn)`, since each printing requires constant amount of time, and number of values `n` will get along the way is `O(logn)`

If you are looking for "real life" examples, in quicksort (and for simplicity let's assume splitting to exactly two halves), you split the array of size `n` to two subarrays of size `n/2`, and then you recurse on both of them - and invoke the algorithm on each half.

This makes the complexity function of:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n)
```

From [master theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Case_2), this is in `Theta(nlogn)`.

Similarly, on binary search - you split the problem to two parts, and recurse only on one of them:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + 1
```

Which will be in `Theta(logn)`

---

The base is not a factor in big O complexity, because

```
log_k(n) = log_2(n)/log_2(k)
```

and log_2(k) is constant, for any constant `k`.

Comment: The simple function example is brilliant. I'm gonna lead with that the next time somebody asks me this question. I usually use merge sort as an example.

Comment: Is `print n` `O(1)` or `O(logn)`?

Comment: @nymk That's going to depend on your assumption. Usually we are assuming dealing with integers is `O(1)`. However, theoretically speaking - yes, it is going to be `O(logN)`, for any size and unbounded integers, since an integer `N` needs `O(logN)` bits/digits to represent

Comment: I realize `print n` in your example is not `O(logn)`, since n  is repeatedly divided by 2.

Comment: @nymk For the general case, where printing is not constant, this will be O((logN)^2). Assume print is printing bits (for simplicity), then each round you remove one bit. which means you print `log(n) + log(n/2) + log(n/4) + ... + 1 = log(n) + (log(n)-1) + (log(n)-2) + ... + 1` This is arithmetic progression, and its sum is in `O(log(n)^2)`.